# How to manage dirty state in material ui?

Tags: reactjs

In Angular we have [dirty](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) property to check if the field is already touched by user or not.

Thi is required for a good UX.

If a field is not touched yet, we don't turn it red to show that it has errors.

I can't find something similar in [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/).

How can I find out if the user has already touched a field or not?

Comment: You can use formik, it's very practical to manage your form validations : https://formik.org/ -- https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#dirty-boolean (it fits perfectly with the use of material ui)

Comment: @PaulHub, thank you. I already know `formik` and other form libraries. I wonder how can I do it in react itself. We have our own **form-base** in react and we prefer to do it in our base.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://react-hook-form.com/ a simple example below:

check the `formState` values and
`console.log("formstate:", formState, formState.dirtyFields);`

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { Checkbox, Input } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Input as AntdInput } from "antd";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const { control, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm();

  console.log("formstate:", formState)
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <Controller
        render={({ field }) => <Input {...field} />}
        name="firstName"
        control={control}
        defaultValue=""
        className="materialUIInput"
      />
      <label>First Name</label>
      <Controller
        render={({ field }) => <AntdInput {...field} />}
        name="lastName"
        control={control}
        defaultValue=""
      />
      <label>Ice Cream Preference</label>
      <Controller
        name="iceCreamType"
        render={({ field }) => (
          <Select
            {...field}
            options={[
              { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
              { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
              { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
            ]}
          />
        )}
        control={control}
        defaultValue=""
      />
      <Controller
        name="Checkbox"
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => <Checkbox {...field} />}
      />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```